# Angular2 $compile directive as AngularJS 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, compilation, angular

Im trying to rewrite my own project from angular 1 to angular 2 and i need compile directive, but i cant rewrite it to do the same job as before.

```
app.directive("compile", compile);
compile.$inject = ["$compile"];
function compile($compile) {
    return function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        $scope.$watch(
          function ($scope) {
              return $scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
          },
          function (value) {
              element.html(value);
              $compile(element.contents())($scope);
          }
        );
    };
}
```

I know there is no watchers in Angular2, but is there any chance i can receive the same functionality in Angular2?

And i need to work with data like this (i mean compile with child compile directive too):

Controller:

```
function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.Test1 = '<div compile="Test2"></div>';
    $scope.Test2 = '<h1>Test!</h1>';
}
```

HTML:

```
<div compile="Test1"></div>
```

Have in mind that the Test1 and Test2 vars can be changed dynamically at any time.

The whole thing should print as result:

```
<div compile="Test1">
    <div compile="Test2">
        <h1>Test!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 does not have any equivalent of `$compile`, intentionally, I would guess because its use is usually an indicator of bad design.

What do you need it for? Do you truly need the ability to dynamically insert *absolutely anything* in your template? If simply choosing one component to display from a premade list of available components is enough, then either `*ngSwitch` or a router can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

[DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html) is the closest you get. With DCL you can insert arbitrary components into the DOM dynamically.